# Como agilizar buscas em banco de dados VB.net / Access97

Tags: sql, vb.net, microsoft-access, datagridview

Uso uma *query* que faz a busca em 3 tabelas diferentes, o retorno dessa query atribuo em um `Datatable` que irá preencher um `Datagridview`.

O problema é que a busca em si, esta um pouco demorada, usei o `TOP` como limitador mas mesmo assim tem uma certa demora. Uso um banco Access 97, todas as tabelas indexadas.

Bem, gostaria de saber se existe algum modo que eu possa usar um cache para agilizar nessa consulta, ou o que posso melhorar em minha *query*, essa demora fica enviável pra mim.

Segue o código:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Pedidos.Número, Clientes.RazaoSocial As [Cliente], vendedores.nome As [Vendedor], Pedidos.Data As [Data], 
Format(Pedidos.Valor, '###,##0.00') As [VrPedido], Pedidos.Flag As [Flag], Pedidos.Status As [Status],Cliente As [codcli], Vendedor As [codVend] 

FROM Pedidos, vendedores, Clientes 

WHERE Lançamento = 0 And Pedidos.vendedor = Vendedores.código And Clientes.CodigoCliente = Pedidos.Cliente ORDER BY data desc, número desc
```

Preenchendo o DataGrid:

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = Nothing
da = New OleDbDataAdapter(MySQL, Conexao)
dt = New DataTable
da.Fill(dt)
Me.DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```

Comment: Só achei estranho o seu código: `da = New OleDbDataAdapter(MySQL, Conexao)`... MySQL ou Access?

Comment: MySQL, é apenas a variável que recebe a query SELECT

Answer (score 1):

O MS Access não é sistema gerenciador de Banco de Dados de verdade e não tem como conseguir a mesma performance de um `SGBD`. Além de outras limitações como o tamanho máximo de 1Gb do arquivo `.mdb` (versão 97).

A minha resposta é: utilize `MySQL`, `PostGres`, `MS SQL`, `NoSQL`, etc.

Caso esta não seja uma opção, o link abaixo tem diversas técnicas para melhorar a performance de uma Base Access:

http://www.fmsinc.com/microsoftaccess/performance.html

Comment: Só um detalhe, por definição o Access é sim um SGBD, porém para um nicho específico (uso em maquinhas pessoais).

Comment: SGBDR não é por definição SGBD: https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sistema_de_gerenciamento_de_banco_de_dados#Exemplos_de_SGBDs

Comment: Todos que você citou são SGBDs que utilizam o modelo relacional: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database_management_system. Então um SGBDR não é um SGBD ?

Comment: Se caso eu usar um SQLServer, o que devo fazer para agilizar essa consulta?
Sem falar que isso será executado em rede!

Answer (score 0):

Já tentou mudar sua query para um `INNER JOIN` ?

```
SELECT TOP 10 Pedidos.Número, Clientes.RazaoSocial As [Cliente], vendedores.nome As [Vendedor], Pedidos.Data As [Data], 
Format(Pedidos.Valor, '###,##0.00') As [VrPedido], Pedidos.Flag As [Flag], Pedidos.Status As [Status],Cliente As [codcli], Vendedor As [codVend] 
FROM Pedidos
INNER JOIN vendedores ON Pedidos.vendedor = Vendedores.código
INNER JOIN Clientes ON Clientes.CodigoCliente = Pedidos.Cliente
ORDER BY data desc, número desc
```

Retirar o `ORDER BY` pode melhorar a performance da *query* também.

Outros pontos que podem afetar a performance:

- Suas tabelas possuem chave primaria?
- Os índices estão definidos? (Não é o seu caso)
- Não existem linhas duplicadas?

Comment: Realmente o ORDER BY, atrasava mesmo a query, porém eu preciso ordenar as 2 colunas em ordem decrescente.

Comment: Se essas colunas tiverem índices na disposição que você utiliza no `ORDER BY` pode ficar mais rápido.

Comment: Tenho índice em ambos e mesmo assim apresenta lentidão.